# How do I add a percent sign to value from UISlider in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uislider

I want to add a percent sign to the value from a UISlider as a string in a UILabel as you move the slider around in swift.

Here is what I have already tried.

```
@IBOutlet weak var label2: UILabel!

@IBAction func slider2(_ sender: UISlider) {
    let val1 = String(Int(sender.value))
    label2.text = String(format: "%.2f%%", val1)
}
```

I was expecting the label to show something like 25.00% and change as you move the slider, but instead it only shows 0.00% even after moving the slider around.

Comment: are you using `sliderValueChanged`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`val1` is a `String` created from an `Int` of the slider's float value. Just get rid of `val1` and use the slider's value.

```
@IBAction func slider2(_ sender: UISlider) {
    label2.text = String(format: "%.2f%%", sender.value)
}
```

Note that it would be better to use `NumberFormatter` with a `numberFormat` of `.percent` instead of using `String(format:)`. This way the value is formatted correctly for the user's locale.

Comment: Thanks, the code you provided worked great, but I went with your suggestion to use NumberFormatter.